# Android Button Does Not Work

Tags: android, button, android-activity

Okay so I am making a application just for fun that has a random number pop up on the screen. If you tap the button with the same number as the random number you get a point, and if you tap the button with the incorrect number, you lose a point. The catch is you only have 10 seconds to score enough points. Anyway I have two main problems with the application. When you tap the correct button, your score does not go up. However, if you tap the incorrect button, the score will go down. I find that to be very odd. Also, I am having trouble setting the content view after the timer runs out, to tell the player if he/she won or not. Do I need to make a separate activity to set a new content view, or do I have a different error?

Thank you for your help!

Here is my Activity Class:

```
package ab.game.crazynumbers;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Level1Activity extends Activity {

Random r;
Timer t;
int random;
double time;
boolean running = false;
TextView showingnumber;
TextView score;
TextView timer;
Handler handler;
Button b1;
Button b2;
Button b3;
Button b4;
Button b5;
Button b6;
Button b7;
Button b8;
Button b9;
Button b0;
int playerscore;
TextView finalscore;
TextView finalscore2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.level_1);

    playerscore = 0;

    showingnumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game_number);
    score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game_score);
    timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game_timer);
    finalscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.finalscore);
    finalscore2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.finalscore2);

    running = true;
    time = 10.0;

    b0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_0);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_2);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_3);
    b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_4);
    b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_5);
    b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_6);
    b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_7);
    b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_8);
    b9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_9);

    randomnumber();

    b1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (1 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (1 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;

        }
    });

    b2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (2 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (2 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    b3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (3 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (3 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    b4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (4 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (4 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    b5.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (5 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (5 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    b6.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (6 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (6 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    b7.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (7 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (7 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    b8.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (8 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (8 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    b9.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (9 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (9 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    b0.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (0 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (0 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    startTimer();

}

public void startTimer() {

    Timer t = new Timer("Game Timer");

    handler = new Handler();

    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (time > 0) {

                time -= 0.1;

                time = Math.round(time * 10.0) / 10.0;

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        timer.setText("Seconds Remaining: " + time);
                    }
                });

            }

            if (time <= 0) {
                this.cancel();
                if (playerscore >= 10) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.win);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            finalscore.setText("Your Final Score Is "
                                    + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (playerscore < 10) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.lose);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            finalscore2.setText("Your Final Score Is "
                                    + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                finish();
            }

        }

    },

    // time before start of timer
            0,

            // time before it runs again
            100);

}

public void randomnumber() {

    r = new Random();
    random = r.nextInt(10);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            showingnumber.setText(String.valueOf(random));
        }
    });

}

}
```

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/game_timer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Seconds Remaining: 0.0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/game_score"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Your Score Is 0"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.4"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/b1.1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b1.1"
    android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
    android:text="4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/game_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/game_timer"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="89dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/game_number"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.7"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/game_score"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/b1.4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:text="7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.2"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/b1.1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/b1.1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.5"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/b1.4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/b1.4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.8"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/b1.7"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/b1.7"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.0"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/b1.2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/b1.2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:text="0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.6"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/b1.4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/b1.4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.9"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/b1.7"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/b1.7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/b1.6"
    android:text="9" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.3"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/b1.1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/b1.1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/b1.6"
    android:text="3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I would recommend logging the value of random at the time of the button click. So just add Log.w("RANDOM", "value of random = " + random);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong `if` usage. After correct choosing of button, you are generating next number and ONCE AGAIN checking if `random!=that_button_number`. It happens nearly every time, so its decreasing your score.

```
     if (random == 3) {randomNumber()}else{}
```

not

```
if(random==3){
      randomNumber();
  };     
if(random!=3){};
```

You cannot call `setContentView` on runtime of your appliaction. You will get `RuntimeException`. You can:

- hide one layout, show new by `setVisibility`
- use `Frame layout`
- many other things such as fragment transaction or appending new Views

Comment: This is wrong. `setContentView()` is always used at runtime. If you mean after you have run `onCreate()` you still can do it this way but it can be messier than other alternatives

Answer (score 0):

i had saw your code,i found two problems in your code.
 1.You should   extract the Listener，it is very stupid to write it for each button.
 2. In andoid,it is not allow to operate the UI in other thread,you should use Handle

I am a chinese  and  my english is very poor

Comment: I do not understand what extract the listener means. Could you explain that?

Comment: Please don't tell members that what they are doing is stupid but suggest your opinion of a better way. Secondly, the OP is using `runOnUiThread` which, as the name suggests, runs on the `UI` thread

Answer (score 0):

You are generating a random number right after the score is increased so it is going up but then back down after you hit the next `if`

```
if (1 == random) {
                playerscore++;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                    }
                });
                randomnumber();  // there is a new nunmber
            }

            if (1 != random) {  // this should be an else
                playerscore--;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                    }
                });
                randomnumber();
```

I have put comments in the above code where you are having the problem

> Also, I am having trouble setting the content view after the timer runs out, to tell the player if he/she won or not. Do I need to make a separate activity to set a new content view, or do I have a different error?

without knowing what problems you are having its hard to say. But this can be done. However, I suggest using an [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) for this or you can create a separate `Activity` for this with a `theme` of `Dialog` in the `manifest`

Also, you can use just one listener for all `Buttons` since they all do pretty much the same thing, either in xml by setting the `onClick` function the same for all of them

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1
    ...
    android:onClick="functionName"/>
```

then in java

```
public void functionName(View v)
{
     // v is the button that was clicked
}
```

or in java by implementing your listener, here onClick, with

```
button1.setOnClickListener(this);  // do this for each
public void onClick(View v)
{
    // v is still the button clicked
}
```

Then get the text of the button that was clicked and compare it to the random number